# Android touch events before onCreate finished?

Tags: android

Does Android starts handling screen touches before onCreate has finished? I use setContentView, then I initialize some stuff, if I am really fast and select a list item after the activity is opened I get a null pointer and this could only happen if a variable is not initialized yet. It seems that touches are getting handled after setContentView was called regarding onCreate did not finished yet, is this a true fact? it seems strange to me.

I wrote a simple example so you know what I am meaning:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MainFragment.OnListItemSelected {

private List<String> mList;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ...
    initialize();
    ...
}

private void initialize() {
    mList = new ArrayList{1,2,3};
}

 @Override
public void onListItemSelected(final int id) {
    do something with mList -> NullPointer if this called before initialize() was called
}
```

}

Comment: There is no need for a code for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement a ViewTreeObserver in your code?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html

```
 vto = convertView.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);  //vet inte om denna metod är nödvändig

                    }
               }});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see your list - this means you are way beyond `onCreate()` on the Activity's lifecycle.
So this NullPointer is not due to `initialize()` not being called.
You can also add log outputs on `initialize(),` `onCreate()` and `onResume()` and see for yourself.

Comment: That is the logic assumption and why I am finding this NulPointerException so strange. I will took a look at my code again.

Comment: You'd have to post your code and the stack trace if you want further help with this issue